# Network traffic over Remote Session

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, logging, remote-access, traffic

let's assume I have two computers, A and B, both running in different networks.
I then use a remote desktop tool (i.e. teamviewer) to access computer B from A. What could the network-administrator of network A log/see?

Example: Network A forbids access to *domain.com*, when I now use teamviewer and then access *domain.com* from within the remote session over the network of B, I assume the network A can't log it, right? As the traffic is sent in network B and only the graphics output is transfered over to A?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Does this depend on the program I use for remote access? E.g. what happens when I use UltraVNC, is it the same behaviour and all remote network traffic can't be logged in the current network?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing the administrator of network A will be able to see is that you've connected to computer B, no more than that, as all the communication is transmitted through HTTPS. And it doesn't depend on the software, whether it's Teamviewer or UltraVNC, or any other program available on the market.
Hope that answers you question.